# Alert message when sum of checkboxes is greater than a specific number

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, checkbox

I need your help with something I am trying to create.What I want to build is an alert message displaying to user screen when the sum of the values of the checkboxes is greater than a specific number which is stored in the database table.The thing is that I am using php to echo the checkboxes form..

Here is the form:

```
echo '

     <div>
       <div class="feed-activity-list">
         <div style="border: 0.5px solid green; border-right-style:none;" class="input-group m-b"><span class="input-group-addon"> <input type="checkbox" name="opt" value="'.$points.'"></span>
            <div class="feed-element">
              <a href="profile.html" class="pull-left">
              <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="'. $row_select4['image_url']. '">
              </a>
            <div class="media-body ">
              <div class="ibox-tools">
                  <span class="label label-primary">ΔΙΑΘΕΣΙΜΟ</span><br><br>
                  <span class="label label-warning-light pull-right"><strong>'  .$row_select4['points'].  '</strong> Πόντοι</span>
              </div>
                  <strong>'  .$row_select4['title'].  ' </strong> '   .$row_select4['description'].  ' <br>
                  <small class="text-muted">Διάρκεια: <strong>'  .$row_select4['start_date'].  ' - '   .$row_select4['end_date'].  ' </strong></small>
              <div class="well">
                                                        '  .$row_select4['description'].  '
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

  </div>'  ;
```

And the submit button (outside the php script):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">ΕΞΑΡΓΥΡΩΣΗ</button> 
</form>
```

Finally I am using this script :

```
var sum = 0; 
    var maxSum = <?php echo $form_points;  ?> ; 

    $('[name="opt"]').change(function(){

      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        sum = sum + parseInt($(this).val()); 
      }
      else
      {
        sum = sum - parseInt($(this).val()); 
      }


      if( sum > maxSum )
      {
          ;
          sweetAlert("ΠΡΟΣΟΧΗ", "Υπερβήκατε τους πόντους του πελάτη", "error"); 

      }
    })
```

But now when I click 'OK' on the alert I want remove the check on the last checkbox (that made sum > maxSum) and to run the script again with the values before I check the last checkbox!

Comment: try using javascript for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a jquery script on the bottom of the page.

```
var checkboxes = $('.feed-activity-list input[type=checkbox]');
var limit = 9999999;
var sum = 0;
var limitExceeded;

checkboxes.on('change', function() {
  var input = $(this);
  var inputVal = input.val() - 0;

  if (input.prop('checked')) {
    if ((sum + inputVal) > limit) {
      input.prop('checked', false);
      alert('sum exceeded limit' + limit);
    } else {
      sum += inputVal;
    }
  } else {
    sum -= inputVal;
  }
});
```

And put the sum in a hidden input.

Comment: Ok thanks!Another matter I have now is how can I uncheck the checkbox that makes `sum > 9999999` after ckicking OK..I try something but it removes all the checks I have done..Any ideas?I am not aware of javascript so anything will be helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot man!It works great!But please tell me, you said to put the sum in a hidden input.Why?Is it necessary?

Comment: It's not necessary, I thought you needed the sum on submitting the form.

Comment: I need to store sum value of checkboxes in a database table yes!I am working on it  but for now I don't have right results..If you have any ideas please let me know.Thanks for all!

Comment: Not the right results? What's happening? Shouldn't you name the checkboxes "opt[]" ->  <input name="opt[]" /> so you can loop it as an array at the backend?

Comment: I am trying to do something like that but sum value it isn't right.For example, I check two checkboxes (1st has value=100 and the 2nd has value=200) and the sum is 200

Comment: OK!I think I made it happen!Thanks a lot for your help!Regards!